# Camel smpp special characters for sending sms

Tags: apache-camel, smpp

I'm working on a project where I'm sending messages coming from an activeMQ queue to an sms-c.

This works fine except that I'm currently unable to send special characters used in french like: é è à : those characters are not displayed correctly on mobile phones.

Do you have any idea what I should change in my configuration to send those characters correctly ?

Which smpp options should I change ? http://camel.apache.org/smpp.html

Is it the datacoding, encoding or alphabet I should change ? or probably the combination of the 3.

Answer (score 0):

On the initial tests I did I was setting the dataCoding / alphabet (= 8 UCS2) as URI options. 
This didn't work.

If I set

the alphabet to UCS2 as a Producer Message Header 
and encoding = UTF-16BE as URI options

then it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here are autoconfiguration parameters worked for me

```
camel.component.smpp.configuration.encoding=UTF-16BE
camel.component.smpp.configuration.data-coding=8
```